# Utility to take a screenshot, annotate it (arrows, etc), host it, and put a URL to the hosted image on my clipboard

Tags: mac, screenshot

Is there any utility that will allow me to (on a Mac):

1. Take a screenshot
2. Annotate it (arrows, text, etc)
3. Upload it somewhere
4. Put a link DIRECTLY to the image on my clipboard (i.e., not to some Skitch sharing page or whatever)

Or, just as good, would be a utility that puts a screenshot in my dropbox public folder and adds the appropriate URL to my clipboard (this is what Jing used to do, but it's being discontinued and it doesn't work very well on the MBP retina)

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt that there is anything that fulfills *all* of your requirements in one package, but you have a couple of options to get most of them.

Most image-sharing sites offer an uploader that you can use to upload file(s) and copy links to them.

Some examples include:

- SkyPath for [ImageShack](http://imageshack.us/p/features/)
- OS X Dashboard Widget for [ImgUr](https://imgur.com/apps)
- [Photobucket Uploader](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Internet-Utilities/Photobucket-Uploader.shtml) for Photobucket

Also, depending on the browser you use, you may be able to install a screenshot extension. There are plenty for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/screenshot), [FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=screenshot), [Safari](http://extensions.apple.com/), [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/search/?query=screenshot), and even a few for [IE](http://www.iegallery.com/Search?q=screenshot) but I prefer Google’s [Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg).